# Perturbation of differential equation: does the equilibrium survive?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have the system

$$x'=f(x)$$ with $f$ a $\cal{C}^1$ function and assume $x_0$ is an equilibrium point, that is, $f(x_0)=0$. Let $g$ another $\cal{C}^1$ function and consider the system
$$
x'=f(x)+\varepsilon g(x)
$$

Is is true that, if $\varepsilon$ is close enough to $0$, then the system has an equilibrium $x_\varepsilon$ such that $x(0)=x_0$?

Seems instuitive to me, but I'd like to know the formal reasoning behind. Do I need more hypothesis or is this enough to assure the result?

Comment: Better use $x_{\epsilon}$, isn't it?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes You are right, it's edited now

Comment: You'll need some non-degeneracy assumptions. For a counter-example take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=1$. So you want the fixed point simple, possibly "hyperbolic", that is, eigenvalues of the Jacobian with real part well-away from zero. Then you get persistence of the critical point and of its behavior for "topological" reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_\epsilon$ be such that $f(x_\epsilon)+\epsilon g(x_\epsilon)=0$. Assume that $J_f(x_0)$, the Jacobian of $f$ at $x=x_0$, is invertible, then the implicit function theorem states that

$$\left.\dfrac{dx_\epsilon}{d\epsilon}\right\vert_{\epsilon=0}=-J_f(x_0)^{-1}g(x_0).$$

In other words, $x_\epsilon=x_0-\epsilon J_f(x_0)^{-1}g(x_0)+o(\epsilon)$.

More generally speaking, if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials, then we have that the roots of $f(x)+\epsilon g(x)$ tends to the roots of $f(x)$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero. This is due to the fact that the roots of a polynomial are continuous functions of its coefficients.